# How to ask further questions concerning an old question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I asked a question (to be specific, [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159369/chronicle-of-email-correspondences)) about four months ago and got a completely satisfying answer.

In the meantime I continued my project and built my own solution for the problem by slightly modifying the answer I have gotten, and new questions concerning the same project turned up. They're quite specific and can't be asked in a meaningful way without referring to the project itself.

How should I ask them? Should I ask them as comments in the old question? Should I open new questions? Or should I do something different?

Comment: IMHO the best thing would be opening a new question with a clear reference to the first one, and building up on that. Scientific paper style.

Comment: @MaxD: I suggest opening a new question, with clear explanations why the first question (refer to it) was solved and why/how new 'problems' appeared, otherwise it could be endangered by 'close-voters' (`;-)`) as **duplicate**. I would refrain from adding comments to your old question, since comments have to be short and will be probably not noticed at all (especially in old questions)

Comment: This is very similar to [I've just been told I have to post a follow-up question, why and how?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764)... even though you've "not been told".